# Navigate to specific tab when app comes to foreground from the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I am developing an app which has a `FragmentActivity` in which I have an `ActionBar` with 3 tabs at the top. In each tab I am loading a particular Fragment.

The thing I want to know is when my application is in foreground and suppose user was seeing the third tab and then he presses the `home` button, the application goes in background. When after some time when he taps on the application icon on the homescreen the application will come in foreground and at point of time I want the user to see a particular tab other than the third tab. (which is default behavior).

How can I achieve this ?

I tried using 
`actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(SectionIterator)).setTabListener(this), true);`

in `onCreate()` method but this works only when app is started for the first time and not when app is brought to foreground from the background.

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The way i accomplished this is as suggested by @Omer using the `onResume()` method.

Inside the `onResume()` method I have written the following code

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

int DefaultTabToBeSelected = vGetValueForDefaultTab();

pager.setCurrentItem(DefaultTabToBeSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onResume() method. this method gets called whenever the user comes back into your application after leaving it (but not killing it entirly)

[image]

Comment: can you tell what exactly should I do in onResume() method ?

Comment: Put the exact same code that you have in your onCreate which selects the tab you want in the onResume() method

Comment: the same statement will not work in `onResume()` as tabs are already created and added to the `actionBar`